# Подсчет количества строк в блоке

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Доброго времени суток, Есть вертикальное меню с фиксированной шириной, и в каждом пункте меню разное количество строк, как с помощью js посчитать сколько строк и исходя из этого дать padding? Т.е. Если 2 строки то padding один если одна строка то padding другой.Вот само меню http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/7r4ZC/

Answer (score 2):

А что вам нужно? Сделать текст по центру? Тогда советую не мучаться и сверстать таблицей с `vertical-align: middle;`
Конечно, это не "тру", но должно работать везде.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но дело в том что текст это ссылка, и она должна работать при наведении на весь пункт а не только на текст)),по этому мне нужно дать ему определённый падинг сверху и снизу.

Comment: вообще да, так обычно и делают. а строки считать.. можно посчитать количество символов, которое влезает на одну строку, и исходя из этого дальше работать

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JKfh7/2/ — мой костыль. работает, но функциональность нормальной ссылки урезана — нет всяких "открыть в новой вкладке" и т. п. Я бы не использовал на своем сайте. Вечером еще одну идею попробую.

PS В JSFiddle работает только бинг.

Comment: О, кстати о количестве символов. Это идея!! Спасибо, буду пробовать.